# Does an enqueued React update for a parent element always update the child as well?

Tags: reactjs

Considering a scenario where a Child Component needs to use the props from it's Parent to build part of it's state, if multiple updates within the Parent get enqueued, will the child receive all of these updates and will the child's state reflect these changes accordingly? Or does the child only receive the final update that is used to rerender the components?

*[This is not my use case, but just a simple contrived example]*
As an example, say the parent continuously overwrites a number stored in `state.num`. The Parent passes `state.num` to the child as props.

```
{ // this is a React event handler and thus setState calls should batched
  this.setState({num: 1});
  this.setState({num: 2});
  this.setState({num: 3});
}
```

The child, in `getDerivedStateFromProps`, appends each `props.num` that it receives to its own `state.numArray` so as to build an array of all changes.

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // comparisons and other stuff here
    return {
      numArray: [...state.numArray, props.num]
    };
  }
```

With this setup, will the child receive every single overwritten value from the parent (would Child `numArray` be `[1, 2, 3]`)? Or would it only receive the final Parent `num` value present when rerendering all the components (Parent `num` is `3`, Child `numArray` is `[3]`)?

Links to lines in React source or official docs would be appreciated.

Comment: Both the cases you mentioned are possible.
Thing is we cannot predict the order of batching of `setState`.

React may batch the three `setState` any number of ways i.e batching 1,2 and separate 3 or batching 2,3 and separate 1 or may be batching 1,2,3.

The child re-render as many times as the parent does.

Comment: Hmmm. So from what I understand, updates are different from renders. I'm not concerned about rerenders, but just with updates. So when react performs one of the updates in it's queue, does the update address the component and all it's children? Or does it only set the parent state?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly.
Whenever state/props change, component will update.
If the parent re-renders, child will definitely re-render.

Infact your scenario shouldn't be hard to test. You can create a sandbox and try it out.

Comment: It seems my understanding of child component updates was incorrect. Child components only seem to receive props after the parent re-renders. However I was uncertain as to whether the child component would update with each of the parent's incremental updates, before the parent re-render.

With that in mind, I guess the answer is that it is unpredictable.